# Type of beam to use as a header

Tags: framing, structural, load-bearing, shed

We're building a new duck coop so I've been playing around with some ideas.  Here's my current design:

[image]

The wooden beams are 8x8" beams that are 8 feet tall.  They'll be anchored into the concrete foundation.  Between the beams, there's a giant 8 foot wide window.  It'll probably be polycarbonate, but we might just end up using a really strong steel mesh of some sort to let air in.  My question:

What should I put between the 2 beams to support the roof.  Obviously, there's an 8 foot span between the beams so I'd imagine something pretty hefty.  Would I need another 8x8" beam?  Would a 4x4" work?  Maybe 2 4x4" beams side by side?  I guess the exact mathematical answer would be "depends on the weight of the roof", but just imagine normal roof trusses with plywood and shingles.

Thanks for any tips or advice!

Comment: Need to add in expected snow load and wind load on roof to get a better answer.  Think the 8 x 8s kind of over build, but if you have them and using them to get rid of them, okay.

Comment: I live in Washington, so definitely some snow load but nothing too crazy.  A foot maybe?  We're thinking of a pretty steep roof too.  Definitely no hurricane force winds in WA, but we get the occasional 50mph gusts..  The 8x8 posts are mostly for looks, but yea I'd rather not use them horizontally unless I have to.

Comment: This: https://www.aacounty.org/departments/inspections-and-permits/permit-center/forms-and-publications/Resources/HeaderSpanTable.pdf Suggests you are pushing into LVL territory

Comment: For 8 foot, would use two 2x8s for header.  For strength you want depth, instead of thickness.   Can notch the 8x8s to fit the header lower, than on top of 8x8.

Comment: Lvl beam sounds doable as well, you're thinking 2x8 beam around the entire perimeter of the coop?  I do like the idea of notching it into the vertical beams for added sheer support as well..

Comment: 2x8 or bigger just for window.  Imagine rest of coop be regular house type framing, so you do not want header sticking above wall frame.

Comment: @crip659 That would definitely change the whole look of the thing, since I'd probably have to shorten the beams and put the stone veneer above the glass as well.  Curious if 6" LVL beam would be strong enough..

Comment: Why not shorten the window?